# java.lang.InternalError in Thread.java

Tags: java, android, multithreading

In my application I got an strange crash in some devices. I've never seen this error before. This is the stacktrace

```
Non-fatal Exception: java.lang.InternalError: Thread starting during runtime shutdown
       at java.lang.Thread.nativeCreate(Thread.java)
       at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:1063)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.addWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:921)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.processWorkerExit(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:989)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1131)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

I don't know how to solve it. Please help me!

Comment: could you please share more details (codes, bug cases... etc)

Comment: Go through this link May be helpful for u .https://github.com/ACRA/acra/issues/327

Answer (score 1):

from android sourcecode, when internal exception happened when the thread in nativeCreate, the properly reason is that the process runtime thread is in shutdown state:

```
 // Atomically start the birth of the thread ensuring the runtime isn't        shutting down.
    bool thread_start_during_shutdown = false;
   {
    MutexLock mu(self, *Locks::runtime_shutdown_lock_);
    if (runtime->IsShuttingDownLocked()) {
      thread_start_during_shutdown = true;
    } else { 
      runtime->StartThreadBirth();
    }
  }
  if (thread_start_during_shutdown) { 
    ScopedLocalRef<jclass> error_class(env, env->FindClass("java/lang/InternalError"));
    env->ThrowNew(error_class.get(), "Thread starting during runtime shutdown");
    return;
  }
```